# $ionicModal can't update $scope?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have trouble with updating a `$scope` object when It's inside a Modal.

```
$scope.lists = {};
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('foobar-show.html', function($ionicModal) {
  $scope.modal = $ionicModal;
}, {
  scope: $scope
});
```

As you can see it's the normal `$ionicModal` 
And it opens the Modal with this: `<a ng-click="doOpen()">Modal</a>`

```
$scope.doOpen = function(){
    $scope.modal.show();
    $scope.foobar = {};
};
```

Inside I do a `{{ lists.length }}` > returns `0`

But then I'm calling inside that Modal the function:

```
$scope.fooAction = function(a){
    $scope.lists.push(a);
    alert($scope.lists.length);
};
```

The alert returns a +1. So `1` after the first time, but the View of the modal still returns `0`... Is it a different scope or something? I pass it with the ionicModal, right? How to fix this?

Comment: what do you mean: ", but the View of the modal still returns 0"

Answer (score 0):

Beacause the modal is created the first you enter the view and than is being cached, you have to tell your view not to cache it.

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
```